# Historical database number formatting

Tags: python, sql, ms-access, formatting, number-formatting

Currently I am working with a historical database (in MS Access) containing passages of ships through the Sound (the strait between Denmark and Sweden).

I am having problems with the way amounts of products on board of ships were recorded. This generally takes the following forms:

12 1/15 (integer - space - fraction)

1/4 (fraction)

1 (integer)

I'd like to convert all these numbers to floats/decimal, in order to do some calculations. There are some additional challenges which are mainly caused by the lack of uniform input:

-not all rows have a value

-some rows have value: '-', i'd like to skip these

-some rows contain '*' when a number or a part of a number is missing, these can be skipped too

My first question is: Is there a way I could directly convert this in Access SQL? I have not been able to find anything but perhaps I overlooked something.

The second option I attempted is to export the table (called cargo), use python to convert the value and then output it and import the table again. I have a function to convert the standard three formats:

```
from fractions import Fraction
import pandas
import numpy

def fracToString(number):
    conversionResult = float(sum(Fraction(s) for s in number.split()))
    return conversionResult

df = pandas.read_csv('cargo.csv', usecols = [0,5], header = None, names = ['id_passage', 'amount'])
df['amountDecimal'] = df['amount'].dropna().apply(fracToString)
```

This works for empty rows, however the values containing '*' or '-' or other characters that the fractToString function can't handle raise a ValueError. Since these are just a couple of records out of over 4 million these can be omitted. Is there a way to tell pandas.apply() to just skip to the next row if the fracToString function throws a ValueError?

Thank you in advance,

Alex

Comment: Of course this can be done in Access SQL in conjunction with VBA user-defined functions. It can be done without them as well, though that will require some work.

Comment: Though if this is being queried from python then VBA UDFs won't execute. I'd think the solution is either python or SQL.

Comment: @Brad This Python code seems to read an exported CSV, instead of directly connecting to Access using ODBC. An UDF might be valid, and likely is the easiest solution. I'm waiting for OP to reply though.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have some bad experiences with using ODBC through python with all kinds of driver issues so I was keen to avoid it. I also have zero experience in VBA. I botched something together to produce a new csv file and joined this to the original table. Not the most elegant solution but it works for now. Again, thanks for thinking along!